# onclick="console.log($(this).text());" to html div or p id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
for(i = 0;i < val.length; i++){
    k+= '<td onclick="console.log($(this).text());" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" title="Click to open modal">' + val[i].customId + '</td>';
    k+= '</tr>';
}
```

Hello, I have this loop and I need to get customId to modal/dialog.
I get correct customId from console.log, but didn't get result to div or p.
Tryed appendTo ect, but now I'm stuck.

Comment: Your html code and javascript if possible.

Comment: what? so it works? what exactly is the problem?

Comment: in my html I want customId to <p id="custom_id" style="color:white">Custom id result: "customId HERE"</p>

Comment: Can you supply full code? and val variable value for testing

Comment: try this $("<p id='custom_id' style='color:white'>Custom id result: "+$(this).text()+"</p>").appendTo('divID');

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Comment: @eifte can you show me where you applied code to append?is it inside loop?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="custom_id" style="color:white">ID: </div>
```

JS

```
<td onclick="loopTemp = $(this).text(); nameChange();"

function nameChange() { 
    $("<p>" + loopTemp + "</p>").appendTo("#custom_id"); 
}
```